# Custom Field Search via GetList

Tags: acumatica

We have created three custom field for the StockItem screen (see attached image).

[Oz Custom Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPKOK.png)

We would like to search via the Web Services Endpoint (WSE) 5.30.001 using one of these CustomFields, to achieve this we created a new OzStockItem element in our WSE definition [Oz WSE Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnNk6.png) and are attempting to use this via the following code.

```
var itemList = c.GetList(new OzStockItem { OzMinCount = new IntSearch { Condition = IntCondition.IsGreaterThan, Value = 0 } }, false).Cast<OzStockItem>();
```

However instead of getting back a list of the items that match the filter it is failing with the following error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.
---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExportTableToEntitiesMapper.<MapCustomFields>d__28.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExportTableToEntitiesMapper.<MapEntitiesInner>d__26.MoveNext()
at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExportTableToEntitiesMapper.<MapEntities>d__25.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(EntityGateBase gate, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph)
at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGate.GetList(Entity entity, Boolean returnFullEntities)
```

Please could someone advise what we are missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that `OzMinCount` field is integer, not some other numeric type?

Comment: Which Acumatica version are you running?

Comment: Thank you the issue was the field type, we had originally created the fields as Integer but changed them in a later update to Decimal and forgot to update the code.